# Proper way to push a new item onto a state object's array in react native?

Tags: arrays, react-native

I'm struggling to properly add a new element to my state object's array field:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    mockInterest: '',
    interest: [],
    testUser: new User()
  }
}
addItem = () => {
  this.setState({
    // this adds interest to local interest array 
    interest: this.state.interest.concat(this.state.mockInterest)
  })
}
handleClick = () => {

  console.log("logged interest: " + this.state.mockInterest)
  // this logs blank elemnts into the array - no good
  this.setState({
    testUser: {
      interest_tags: [...this.state.testUser.interest_tags, this.state.interest]
    }
  })
  console.log("New interests: " + this.state.testUser.interest_tags)
}
<View style={styles.interestInputView}>
  {/* Interest Input */}
  <TextInput
    style={styles.interestInputText}
    placeholder='Enter an Interest'
    onChangeText={(text) => {
      this.setState({ mockInterest: text })
    }}
  >
  </TextInput>
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.plusImageContainer}
    onPress={this.addItem, this.handleClick}>
    <Image
      style={styles.plusImage}
      source={require('../assets/baseline_add_black_18dp.png')}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Currently, I can only save the text as a *mockInterest* but when I want to add that to the *testUser* object (which has an interest_tag array field) in the state, the mockInterest isn't added to the array, interest_tags.

What am I doing wrong? I tried implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661905/how-to-get-values-which-are-in-textinput-when-button-is-click-in-reactnative) but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tyr to use prevState

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  testUser: {
    ...prevState.testUser,
    interest_tags: [this.state.mockInterest, ...prevState.testUser.interest_tags]
  },
}));
```

**Note:** setState is async call So you need to wait for a second before reading its value.

Comment: I actually want to add the items to the User.interest_tags field. Would this solution work if I substituted the proper names in here or should I go another route when assigning a state object? @Rajan

Comment: I tried this: `this.setState(prevState => ({
            interest_tags: [this.state.testUser.interest_tags, ...prevState.interest]
        }))` but still no luck. @Rajan

Comment: `this.state = {
            mockInterest: '',
            interest: [],
            testUser : {id = -1,
                             first_name = "UNSET",
                             last_name = "UNSET",
                            email = "UNSET",
                            age = -1,
                           gender = "UNSET",
                          classification = "UNSET",
                          major = "UNSET",
                          interest_tags = []}
        }` is this what you mean?

Comment: This works. Would you mind explaining this a bit? Is prevState saving the previous state of testUser, and then the new interest is concatenated with the previous state object's array? And since setState is an asynchronous function, can I make its wrapper function async to accommodate the delay, that way the array's updates can be seen as they're added? @Rajan